# Как узнать размер блока usb flash?

Tags: железо, flash-память

Flash-память, как известно, пишется блоками. Файловые системы тоже пишут данные блоками. Суть вопроса в том, чтобы отформатировать "флэшку" с таким размером кластера, который будет кратен размеру физического блока памяти. А для этого нужно узнать этот размер.

Comment: Сервисные утилиты для работы с флэшками уже ковырял?

Comment: @don Rumata это какие? На сайте производителя нет ничего.

Comment: Коллега советует `MPTool` например. И почитать https://www.usbdev.ru/articles/detect_controller/

Comment: @don Rumata MPTool даже не нашёл флешку. Помог ChipGenius

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Размер блока может показать ChipGenius

8К - значит 8КБайтные блоки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]